# Custom sidebar addon for Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a simple add-on for Google Docs. It basically a list of items I want to have visible on the side when I am using Docs. I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) simple tutorial.

I don't want to publish such a simple add-on unnecessarily. Is there a way that I could use it just within my Google Docs without publishing it ?

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58316700/6057811

Answer (score 1):

If you've just copied the sample code into your document's script, it already works there. To activate the script you have to reopen the document, then in the menus at the top click `Custom Menu -> Show sidebar`.

You only have to publish a script if you want to share your add-on with other users.

If you still have problems, take a look at [Add-on Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs). It describes add-on creation process in details.