# Google docs install my own addon without publishing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, drive

[This question was asked a while ago, but as it is an old question, I made a new one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332913/using-my-own-google-drive-addon-without-publishing-it)

I am trying to install a google docs addon that I just made. I want to install it so I can use it on any document, but I do not want to publish it. I have seen options for privately publishing it, but as far as I can see that requires a $5 developer fee that **I DO NOT WANT TO PAY.** Is there a way that I can do this? Thank you in advance,

Albert

Comment: Except for copying and pasting your code to each document, there is no other easy way. If you are willing to modify your code to a standalone script,  perhaps a web app, where you can select the document you are working on. Then you can run your add on the selected document. Especially if your add on runs off a side bar, you can convert it into a web app pretty easily.

Comment: Your only other option is to use a library.  But a library will require that the project key be put into every script that needs access to the library.  [Link to Apps Script documentation - libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58316700/6057811